# изменить цвет заголовка при наведении на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Сразу к делу - как изменить заголовок в определенной карте а не во всех?

Вот если в вкратце!

```js
var buyNow = $('.buy-now'),
    cardHeading = $('.card-heading');
    
buyNow.mouseover( function (){
  cardHeading.css('background-color', 'red');
})
```

```css
.shop-cards{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-bottom: 87px;
}
.card{
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  width: 370px;
  height: 494px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid inherit;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 9px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.card-heading{
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% / 3.4);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: $primary-color;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid $primary-color;
}
.card-body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 50px 70px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: $text-color;
  font-size: 18px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shop-cards">
    
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-heading">
      <span class="currency">$</span><span class="price"> 49 <span class="period">/month</span></span>
    </div> <!-- //card-heading -->

    <div class="card-body">
      <span class="entery-date border">entery date: mon - fri</span>
      <span class="entery-time border">entery time: 8a.m - 8p.m</span>
      <span class="advicer">nutrition advicer: no</span>

      <button class="btn buy-now" type="submit">Buy now</button>
    </div> <!-- //card-body -->
  </div> <!-- //card -->

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-heading">
      <span class="currency">$</span><span class="price"> 49 <span class="period">/month</span></span>
    </div> <!-- //card-heading -->

    <div class="card-body">
      <span class="entery-date border">entery date: mon - fri</span>
      <span class="entery-time border">entery time: 8a.m - 8p.m</span>
      <span class="advicer">nutrition advicer: no</span>

      <button class="btn buy-now" type="submit">Buy now</button>
    </div> <!-- //card-body -->
  </div> <!-- //card -->

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-heading">
      <span class="currency">$</span><span class="price"> 49 <span class="period">/month</span></span>
    </div> <!-- //card-heading -->

    <div class="card-body">
      <span class="entery-date border">entery date: mon - fri</span>
      <span class="entery-time border">entery time: 8a.m - 8p.m</span>
      <span class="advicer">nutrition advicer: no</span>

      <button class="btn buy-now" type="submit">Buy now</button>
    </div> <!-- //card-body -->
  </div> <!-- //card -->

</div> <!-- //shop-cards -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var buyNow = $('.buy-now'),
    cardHeading = $('.card-heading');
    
buyNow.mouseover( function (){
  $(this).closest(".card").find(".card-heading").css('background-color', 'red');
})
```

```css
.shop-cards{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-bottom: 87px;
}
.card{
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  width: 370px;
  height: 494px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid inherit;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 9px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.card-heading{
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% / 3.4);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: $primary-color;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid $primary-color;
}
.card-body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 50px 70px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: $text-color;
  font-size: 18px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shop-cards">
    
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-heading">
      <span class="currency">$</span><span class="price"> 49 <span class="period">/month</span></span>
    </div> <!-- //card-heading -->

    <div class="card-body">
      <span class="entery-date border">entery date: mon - fri</span>
      <span class="entery-time border">entery time: 8a.m - 8p.m</span>
      <span class="advicer">nutrition advicer: no</span>

      <button class="btn buy-now" type="submit">Buy now</button>
    </div> <!-- //card-body -->
  </div> <!-- //card -->

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-heading">
      <span class="currency">$</span><span class="price"> 49 <span class="period">/month</span></span>
    </div> <!-- //card-heading -->

    <div class="card-body">
      <span class="entery-date border">entery date: mon - fri</span>
      <span class="entery-time border">entery time: 8a.m - 8p.m</span>
      <span class="advicer">nutrition advicer: no</span>

      <button class="btn buy-now" type="submit">Buy now</button>
    </div> <!-- //card-body -->
  </div> <!-- //card -->

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-heading">
      <span class="currency">$</span><span class="price"> 49 <span class="period">/month</span></span>
    </div> <!-- //card-heading -->

    <div class="card-body">
      <span class="entery-date border">entery date: mon - fri</span>
      <span class="entery-time border">entery time: 8a.m - 8p.m</span>
      <span class="advicer">nutrition advicer: no</span>

      <button class="btn buy-now" type="submit">Buy now</button>
    </div> <!-- //card-body -->
  </div> <!-- //card -->

</div> <!-- //shop-cards -->
```

Comment: Как бы до такого же уровня в JS дойти как и вы?)

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич да я почти ничего не знаю )

Comment: Вы мне уже не на один десяток, наверное, вопросов помогли ответить)

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич а эти приемчики надо один раз увидеть - и привет, всю жизнь будете знать

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич Кстати говоря. Я видел вчера Ваш вопрос про `select`, но не понял, в чем дело. Вы можете это воспроизвести в песочнице?

Comment: Я уже лёг спать, завтра заново создам, думаю вы по фильтрам найдёте, суть вопроса была только в safari и исключительно на разрешении < 1024px экрана, хотя я раньше с таким никогда не сталкивался)